# CSS puro para fazer progresso em círculo

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer um círculo de progresso, mas não estou conseguindo.
Eu quero exatamente dessa forma.

1. Quero um círculo preto.
2. Uma borda em cinza menor que esse círculo, tipo uns 5px a menos.
3. Um círculo que é o progresso.

Achei algumas dicas na internet mas não estou conseguindo colocar em prática.
Não consigo fazer o círculo entender a porcentagem correta.

Até agora, fiz isso abaixo:

```css
.percent {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slice {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.bar {
  border: 4px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 30px, 30px, 0);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="percent">
  <div class="slice">
    
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tomei um negativo aqui sem motivos. Até quando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego vamos por partes.

Primeiro o estilo `clip:rect();` *foi descontinuado*. Agora o que se usa é o `Clip-Path`

Além disso o ***Rect*** quer dizer retângulo, antão nunca daria certo trabalhar com ele em forma de círculo. Para isso existe o `clip-path:circle();`

Referência do `clip:rect();` (*deprecated*): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Referência do `clip-path:circle();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

---

Agora vamos ao que interessa, o código!

Usei como base o design e código que você postou, e fiz a animação usando `@keyframes` está 100% CSS não tem script. A técnica que eu usei não usa o `clip:rect();` mas o resultado pode te interessar...

É um modelo bem simples mesmo, mas é para fins didáticos e você ver funcionando com o seu próprio código. Se quiser depois te passo uns links com modelo mais sofisticados só com CSS também.

```css
.percent {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .slice {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .bar1 {
    border: 4px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    -webkit-animation: loader1 4s linear infinite;
            animation: loader1 4s linear infinite;
    }
    .bar2 {
    border: 4px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    -webkit-animation: loader2 4s linear infinite;
            animation: loader2 4s linear infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes loader1 {
        0% {
            border-top: 4px solid transparent;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        }
        25% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        }
        50% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid red;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        }
        75% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid red;
            border-bottom: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        }
        100% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid red;
            border-bottom: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 4px solid red;
        }
    }

    @keyframes loader1 {
        0% {
            border-top: 4px solid transparent;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        }
        25% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        }
        50% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid red;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        }
        75% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid red;
            border-bottom: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        }
        100% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid red;
            border-bottom: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 4px solid red;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes loader2 {
        0% {
            border-top: 4px solid transparent;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        25% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                    transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        50% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid red;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                    transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        75% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 4px solid red;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
                    transform: rotate(270deg);
        }
        100% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid red;
            border-bottom: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 4px solid red;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @keyframes loader2 {
        0% {
            border-top: 4px solid transparent;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        25% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid transparent;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                    transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        50% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
            border-left: 4px solid red;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                    transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        75% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 4px solid red;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
                    transform: rotate(270deg);
        }
        100% {
            border-top: 4px solid red;
            border-right: 4px solid red;
            border-bottom: 4px solid red;
            border-left: 4px solid red;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="percent">
    <div class="slice"></div>
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="fill"></div>
</div>

<div class="percent" style="margin-left: 100px">
    <div class="slice"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```